# Replacing image src dynamically isn't working

Tags: jquery

```
<img id="img1" data-src="media/sample.jpg"  alt="Image" />
```

```js
self.next().find('[data-src]').each(function (index, value) { 
  var $this = $(this);
  console.log($this.attr('id'));
  $this.attr('src', $this.data('src')); 
});
```

I am attempting to load an image dynamically. I can step through the above code, the selectors are all correct and the correct ID is out put to the console. I I inspect the img in console i can see it has an attribute of src with the correct value but it is not visible in the dom via inspection and no image loads on screen.

I cant understand what is wrong. There are no errors in the console.

[image: Here is the log of this before i add src]

[image: And here is after]

then inspecting the element after src has been added it is

```
<img id="img1" data-src="media/homepage/carousel/owl-article5.jpg" alt="Image for Feature title 1">
```

Comment: Your code works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/ud14881L/. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: `$this.attr('src', $this.attr('data-src'));`

Comment: @AlivetoDie, read this section of question _inspect the img in console i can see it has an attribute of src with the correct value_

Comment: can you give the output of console.log(self)

Comment: thanks, I have updated my question